# SQL to Mongo DB Query for comparing two tables

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm a beginner for mongodb and I have two tables where one is "employees" and the other "assign_work", the tables have the following attributes,

employees:
empno,
name,
email,
contactno,
age

assigned_work:
assignment_name,
empno,
progress,
deadline

I want to get all the values in the employees table where they have been assigned work which is denoted by (progress = "Assigned"). The query I found for mongodb is

```
db.employees.find({"assigned_work.progress":"Assigned"})
```

but when I run this in MongoDB compass I don't get any output.

Comment: empno in assign_work and in employees collection is same , is it relation ?

Comment: yes they are same. They both contain the same empno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregation on employees

```
db.collection('employees').aggregate(
    [{
    $lookup:{
    from:"assign_work",
    localField:"empno"
    foreignField:"empno"
    as:"assigned_work"
    }
    },
    {
    $match:{“assigned_work.progress":"Assigned"}
    }])
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that now the query worked,  but I'm not getting an output from mongo compass and I tried via postman and I got an empty array

Comment: I double checked my list of  elements and there seemed to be no issue, I adjusted the query with the missing syntax as well

Comment: I forgot “ in match stage

Comment: It worked well, there was an error with the syntax. Thank you very much. Is it possible to count the number of "Assigned" for each empno?

Comment: yeah just provide smaple json data